# C# Server Side confirm dialogue in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the result of the following (whetheryes or no was clicked):

On button click:

```
//First I am checking validations
//Then I am checking if pay grade is being overridden from the business layer
//If it is overriden:
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "confirm('You are overriding the existing pay grade. Do you want to Override ?');", true);
//If the user clicks Yes, more code to save new pay grade in the database is executed.
//Else nothing is done.
```

If Yes is clicked I want to continue executing the code below else, else code below is not executed

Answer (score 0):

Add the return before the confirm dialogue

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "return confirm('You are overriding the existing pay grade. Do you want to Override ?');", true);
```

Comment: `I want to continue executing the code below else, else code below is not executed`, how is this going to do that? Is it going to stop the processing on the server and then continue when the user chooses a response? I think not.

Comment: When user choose yes then dialogue return the true otherwise false. so the executing of code depend on the user choice.

Comment: Not at all. The server-side code isn't going to stop processing and wait for a response. The client and server aren't even connected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're going to have here is that the server is not connected to the client. The server isn't going to stop processing and wait for the user's response and then resume processing from this line of code. You need to write the JavaScript for this and then issue a call back to the server based on the response.

Comment: Is there an alternative then/what can I do?

Comment: @user1986761, not really. You need to use JavaScript to call back into the server. What you would want to do is write the `confirm` dialog JavaScript so that you can call a function client-side that then submits server-side.